# How can I test if my method is returning the right vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++ and I created am creating a game for my class. The game has a player who has territories, and I need to create a method that that returns the vector list of the player's territories.

```
Player::Player(std::vector<Territory> territories) {
     _territories = territories;
}


std::vector<Territory> Player::toDefend() {
    return _territories;

}
```

Essentially, I want to run the method toDefend() in my main and see an output of the vector territories. How can I do that?

EDIT: This is the Territory constructor

```
#include "Territory.h"

Territory::Territory() : continent(nullptr), armies(0), index(0)//, owner(nullptr)
{
}

Territory::Territory(std::string territoryName, Continent& cont, int a, int i) //: owner(nullptr)
{
    index = i;
    name = territoryName;
    continent = &cont;
    armies = a;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what Territory is. You should copy here its class or struct declaration.

Comment: Declare the constructor as `Player::Player(const std::vector<Territory> & territories) {
     _territories = territories;
}` if you want the code to be correct and avoid redundant copies of the territory list.

Comment: @PabloAriel thank you, I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming `Territory` has a `toString()` method (if not create one that returns the territory name)

```cpp
std::string Territory::toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Just iterate through the `std::vector` and display each `Territory`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<Territory> myTerritories;
    // populate with Territories
    Player player(myTerritories);
    for (const Territory &t : player.toDefend())
        std::cout << t.toString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You should probably also change the constructor of Player to the code below to prevent an unnecessary copy being created.

```cpp
Player::Player(std::vector<Territory> &territories) {
     _territories = territories;
}
```